# copyq paste works slow for terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, clipboard

I'm using Pop!_OS 20.04, gnome-terminal as terminal emulator, and CopyQ as clipboard manager.

What I've noticed is, whenever I'm trying to paste in the terminal window (just a plain old local session, nothing but `bash` running), there's a significant variable delay about 0.7 seconds before the text appears. At the same time, pasting in anything else - be that browser or a text editor - works blazingly fast. It's not that I'm pasting anything large - only few characters long.

If I quit CopyQ, pasting starts to act normal in terminal as well.

If with running CopyQ I, instead of pressing the paste shortcut, I press right mouse button and select "Paste" from there, it also works as usual.

Didn't play much with CopyQ configs, so nothing to show in this regard.

Installed Kitty just for the sake of trying, the behaviour is the same.

Where could the problem be?

UPDATE: changed my WM to vanilla i3, still no change in behaviour. It's not GNOME.